# Singly Linked List - get and add methods

Tags: java, node.js, linked-list, queue, singly-linked-list

So I'm trying to implement an SLList class by completing the implementations:

`get(i)`, `set(i, x)`, `add(i, x)`, and `remove(i)` operations, each running in O(1 + i) time.

What I'm struggling with my program is the add and get methods. I keep getting the errors `incompatible types: SLList<T>.Node cannot be converted to int` and also `incompatible types: SLList<T>.Node cannot be converted to int`.

I'm very confused as to how to fix them. I just learned about linked lists today and I'm struggling to grasp the concept of them. Any help or hints would be really appreciated.

```
public T get(int i) {
    // TODO: Implement this
    Node u = head;
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
        i = u.next;
    }
    return u;
    if (i < 0 || i > n - 1) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    return null;
}


public void add(int i, T x) {
        Node u = new Node();
        u.x = x;
        if (i == 0) {
            head = u;
        } else {
            tail.next = u;
        }
        tail = u;
        i++;
        return true;
        if (i < 0 || i > n) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
}
```

I should mention the type of each function T and void must stay as they are. Also I believe I should include the IndexOutOfBoundsException part in my code.

If you guys want to see my full code its here: https://pastebin.com/nJ9iMjxj

Comment: your `get` method returns `Node` instead of `T`. and your `add` method should not return `true` because it's been declared as `void`

Comment: can i see your `node` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `node` class, the type of `next` is `node`, while in your `get` method, you are assigning a `node` to an integer variable :

`i = u.next;`

i don't see the whole implementation of yours, but i think it should be `u = u.next;`

Answer (score 1):

In your `get` method you are trying to assign a `Node` to an `int` variable on line 5. Instead, you should write `u=u.next;`